# Swift add params to request

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I'm trying to add an email and a password to a `NSURLSession` `request` like this:

```
 @IBAction func btnLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
        let email = txtEmail.text
        let password = txtPassword.text
        let data = ["email": email!, "password": password!] as Dictionary<String, String>
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://temp.com/api/v1/login")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        do {
        request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(data, options: [])
        }
        catch {
            print("error!")
        }
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (data, response, error) in
            guard let response = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse else {print(error); return}
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                print("ingelogd!")
            }
            self.errorLogin()
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

error:

```
2016-07-03 17:54:04.890 EmployeeDirectory2[4693:133721] *** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:386
2016-07-03 17:54:04.894 EmployeeDirectory2[4693:133721] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'
```

But when I try this it crashes. How can I add parameters appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is probably coming from the call to `self.errorLogin()` call, which tries to do some UI task outside the main thread. You should be able to fix it like this:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    (data, response, error) in
    guard let response = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse else {print(error); return}
    if response.statusCode == 200 {
        print("ingelogd!")
    }
    // Add this:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.errorLogin()
    }
 }
```